# Npm "yo" command error

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman

I am trying to use the angular-generator but when I used "yo" command i get the following error:

```
module.js:338
    throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'rx'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Luis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\nod
e_modules\inquirer\lib\ui\prompt.js:6:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
```

I try to update yeoman using "npm update -g yo" but I didn't receive any answer in the command line

Comment: Did you try to update npm itself ?

Comment: From their [tutorial page](http://yeoman.io/learning/index.html) the install command should look like: `npm install -g yo bower grunt-cli gulp`, have you done that? Worst case, `npm install -g rx` and see if that gets you past this error.

Comment: My node version is v.0.12. Do I need to update it?

Comment: Thanks @Tony. That solves my problem. I didn't figure out that

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments:

From their [tutorial page](http://yeoman.io/learning/index.html) the install command should look like:

`npm install -g yo bower grunt-cli gulp`

Worst case, `npm install -g rx` and see if that gets you past this error.